# ES2015 vs ESM2015

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I want to understand the difference between ES2015 and ESM2015. I know that ES2015 is the ES^ standards but recently while compiling my Angular application using `ng build` I got the following : 
`Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015`

I want to know why ESM2015? Is it minified ES2015 files?

Comment: seems like the title has a typo. it is ES2015 twice

Comment: @IAfanasov : thanks will correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Angular Package Format](https://angular.io/guide/angular-package-format#definition-of-terms):

> Short for ECMAScript Modules. A file containing statements that import and export symbols. This is identical to the definition of modules in the ECMAScript spec.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js

Comment: When you only post a link, you are forcing visitors to blindly click it. Even worse, in this case the link is broken. Please bring the answer to SO an add the link only as a reference.

Answer (score 6):

When a project is compiled from es2015 to esm2015, like `Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015`

**Basically it is still EcmaScript, but esm is based on modules "or packages"**, this allows to make some parts of the code independent from others.

> **Other differences between modules and standard scripts:**
>
> - modules use strict mode automatically.
> - modules are deferred automatically (when are loading).
> - Modules are only executed once, even if they have been referenced in multiple  tags.
> - Modules features are imported into the scope of a single script — they aren't    available in the global scope.

[more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js)